# Предлоги "в" и "во"

Tags: лексика

Почему мы говорим "во сне", но в то же время - "в себе", "в связи"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в двух словах, то "во" (а также "ко" и "со") произносится перед скоплением согласных. Но тоже не всяких, а тех, перед которыми ещё одна согласная может вызвать затруднения. 
Подробнее - см., например, словарь Аванесова (сопроводительная статья).