# Во Ржеве // В Ржеве

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Есть зерновая культура рожь. Пишется "во ржи".
Есть город Ржев в Тверской области. Как правильно: ***во*** Ржеве или ***в*** Ржеве?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE

Answer (score 1):

**Пишется "во ржи".**

Пишется по-разному. Например: "в ржи много питательных веществ". Хотя "во ржи" употребляется чаще и звучит привычнее.

**Есть город Ржев в Тверской области. Как правильно: "во Ржеве" или "в Ржеве"?**

Здесь можете чувствовать себя ещё свободнее, поскольку оба предлога употребляются почти на равных. Выбирайте тот вариант, который в конкретном предложении кажется Вам более благозвучным.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, "в ржи" можно (но не обязательно) говорить только в смысле "в растении рожь", да еще если рожь используется как мера (см. ниже), в остальных случаях — "во ржи".

В Нацкорпусе:

> Здесь повинности исчислены не только в ржи, но главным образом в деньгах, а также в овсе и жите. [В. Л. Янин. Я послал тебе бересту… (1975)]
>
> При добавлении в питательную среду всего 4 • 10 -10 процента зимазина содержание белка в ржи увеличивалось с 4 до 7 процентов...[обобщенный. Новости отовсюду // «Химия и жизнь», 1968]

Но:

> Во ржи, как и в любом зерне, не так много сахара, а он играет принципиальную роль в процессе брожения. [Дмитрий Михайлин. Односолодовая водка // «Русский репортер», 2015]

[Орфоэпический словарь русского языка](http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0508.htm) Аванесова Р. И. дает:

> во ржи (скрыться и т.д.)

Во Ржеве или в Ржеве? В Нацкорпусе соотношение по количеству документов — 17:8.