# В ДК или во ДК – как правильно?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, аббревиатуры

В случае без аббревиатуры мы пишем **во** дворце культуры. А если сокращение – ДК, то **в** ДК ии **во** ДК?

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в письме, а в произношении прочитанного: ДК на бумаге читается и произносится как буквы алфавита Дэ и Ка. С предлогом скопления согласных не происходит. О скоплении было сказано здесь: [Предлоги "в" и "во"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be)