# Вариант написания: За участие во фотофлешмобе или за участие в фотофлешмобе

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно писать: За участие во фотофлешмобе или за участие в фотофлешмобе?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предлоги "в" и "во"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be)